# How JPA handles null values in entities?

Tags: java, jpa, null

Let's say I have entity:

```
@Entity
public class foo(){
  String field = null;
  //getter and setter
}
```

In database column `field` has default value "bar".

If I persist this entity without setting `field` property to anything other than null, will the field column in inserted record have value `null` or `bar`?

(In the other words, will the null field be included in insert statement with `null` value or will be skipped in insert statement and default value will be used?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the annotation

```
@Column(insertable = false)
private String field = null;
```

will prevent the `field` property being added to the generated SQL. And then the column default value will be used.

Otherwise the `null` field be included in insert statement with `null` value. If the column is marked with `not null`, a database error will be raised. But if `null` is a valid value for the column, then `null` will be persisted.

Answer (score 0):

If your database table has a not null constraint for a given column, then persisting your entity will throw an exception with a message Null values not accepted for the given column. 
If your database table allows nulls for that particular column persisting an entity with a null field will set the field to null even if your table has a default value.
I could be wrong but that is the observation I have drawn with using JPA in my project.